# How to get a specific object from a group in HERE maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I want to get a specific object from a group, for example I have the following objects:

```js
var circleGroup = new H.map.Group({
            volatility: true, 
            objects: [theCircle, circleOutline]
        });

this._circle = circleGroup;
```

And I want to get the value of the object "theCircle", I'm using the below code to get the value of the object "theCircle" but it does not work.

```js
_circle.getObjects()[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can create H.map.Group of objects and you are right about the method to access specific object by calling **_circle.getObjects()[0];**

Creating H.map.Group

```js
circleGroup = new H.map.Group({
        volatility: true 
      });

  // put all objects into one group
  circleGroup.addObjects([circle, polygon, rect, polyline]);
```

I have modified the example in the below link that implements H.map.Group
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/geoshapes/draggable-shapes

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/raj0665/q7agonfb/7/

In this example:

```js
 // place group with all objects on the map
  map.addObject(draggableGroup); 
  //To access just circle on the map, comment above line and uncomment below code of line
   // map.addObject(_draggableGroup.getObjects()[0]);
```